# How do I mount two similar ZFS file systems?

Tags: 22.04, zfs

I have two drives with encrypted ZFS partitions on them: sda and sdd.

How can I mount the sda5 partition to /media/sda5 and the sdd5 partition to /media/sdd5?

The sdd drive is a USB thumb drive and sda is the internal drive.

Both drives contain a fresh install of Ubunru.

```
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1                                                                                                
├─sda2           vfat        FAT32                                 
├─sda3           crypto_LUKS 2                
├─sda4           zfs_member  5000  bpool
└─sda5           zfs_member  5000  rpool

sdd                                                                                                   
├─sdd1                                                                                                
├─sdd2           vfat        FAT32                                 
├─sdd3 
├─sdd4           zfs_member  5000  bpool
└─sdd5           zfs_member  5000  rpool
```

Comment: sda is not a partition, you can't mount it. The same for sdd.

Comment: I updated the question. @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finding the encryption key**

```
gdisk -l /dev/sda

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048            4095   1024.0 KiB  EF02  
   2            4096         1054719   513.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   3         1054720         5249023   2.0 GiB     8200  
   4         5249024         9443327   2.0 GiB     BE00  
   5         9443328       488397134   228.4 GiB   BF00
```

These partitions were created by the Ubuntu 22.04 installer. Partitions 1 and 2 are EFI, partition 3 is encrypted swap and partitions 4 and 5 are zfs:

```
# blkid /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3: UUID="46081d1f-4d72-44d0-9bff-dc9ebda4f590" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="4d56cb7e-69a9-2849-9c20-eb9688669b76"
# blkid /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4: LABEL="bpool" UUID="14572403564643613467" UUID_SUB="7325057841745216519" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="1773b78d-af63-0548-862a-8dd9f0a74800"
# blkid /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5: LABEL="rpool" UUID="6561332372469175307" UUID_SUB="3722037216287012081" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTUUID="2905452c-9f72-3042-b010-97663c37194c"

zfs import bpool
zfs import rpool
zpool status -v
 
pool: bpool
     state: ONLINE
    config:
    
        NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        bpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          1773b78d-af63-0548-862a-8dd9f0a74800  ONLINE       0     0     0
    
    errors: No known data errors
    
      pool: rpool
     state: ONLINE
    config:
    
        NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          2905452c-9f72-3042-b010-97663c37194c  ONLINE       0     0     0
    
    errors: No known data errors

# zfs list -o name,type,keylocation 
NAME                                              TYPE        KEYLOCATION
bpool                                             filesystem  none
bpool/BOOT                                        filesystem  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_aqj46w                          filesystem  none
rpool                                             filesystem  file:///run/keystore/rpool/system.key
rpool/ROOT                                        filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w                          filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/srv                      filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/usr                      filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/usr/local                filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var                      filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/games                filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/lib                  filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/lib/AccountsService  filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/lib/NetworkManager   filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/lib/apt              filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/lib/dpkg             filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/log                  filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/mail                 filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/snap                 filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/spool                filesystem  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_aqj46w/var/www                  filesystem  none
rpool/USERDATA                                    filesystem  none
rpool/USERDATA/andrew_rh4h1s                      filesystem  none
rpool/USERDATA/root_rh4h1s                        filesystem  none
rpool/keystore                                    volume      none
```

Looking at this I can see that I have imported two pools: bpool and rpool. Bpool has one dataset: BOOT. rpool has three datasets: ROOT, USERDATA and keystore. EUREKA! That keystore dataset sounds like something we might want to look at. And look at the Keylocation parameter for rpool: it includes that keystore word. So let’s have a closer look at the keystore dataset. It is of type volume. This is a type that zfs uses to store raw, unformatted data. From the manual:

A ZFS volume is a dataset that represents a block device. ZFS volumes are identified as devices in the /dev/zvol/{dsk,rdsk}/pool directory. In the following example, a 5-GB ZFS volume, system1/vol, is created: # zfs create -V 5gb system1/vol. Be careful when changing the size of the volume.

So maybe this dataset is a luks volume storing the zfs keys?

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/zvol/rpool/keystore  keystore
Enter passphrase for /dev/zvol/rpool/keystore: (enter key used in the ubuntu installer when you created the encrypted zfs install)
# mkdir /mnt/keystore
# mount /dev/mapper/keystore /mnt/keystore/
# ls /mnt/keystore/
lost+found  system.key
# hexdump /mnt/keystore/system.key 
0000000 81de 1df7 a36e 6fd2 7cdf 367a 4e4a 0601
0000010 9679 0be2 7445 bbbd 853c 6f07 79fe ad28
0000020
```

Hooray! That looks like a 512bit system key.

**Mounting the ZFS root**

Change the mountpoint

We don’t want the rpool/ROOT filesystem to clobber our root filesystem. So change the mountpoint.

```
# mkdir /mnt/rpool
# zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/rpool rpool
```

Looking back at the keylocation property for rpool, we know that zfs expects to find the decryption key at /run/keystore/rpool/system.key. So we need to create that subdirectory and move the key to that location

```
# mkdir -p /run/keystore/rpool
# cp /mnt/keystore/system.key //run/keystore/rpool
```

For some reason the rpool canmount property is set to off. So we set that to on, load the key and mount it.

```
# zfs set canmount=on rpool
# zfs load-key rpool
# zfs mount rpool
# ls //mnt/rpool
```

and nothing is there. That’s because I mounted the pool, not the datasets. I could mount all the datasets quickly using the zfs mount -a command but that would clobber many of my existing folders. And looking back at the listing of datasets I see that each line in this list is a mountpoint and there are a lot of them. I just want the USERDATA/andrew_rh4h1s information so I will mount that.

```
# mkdir -p //mnt/rpool/USERDATA/andrew_rh4h1s
# zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/rpool/USERDATA/andrew_rh4h1s rpool/USERDATA/andrew_rh4h1s
# ls -ah //mnt/rpool/USERDATA/andrew_rh4h1s
```

Done! Now I can copy all my stuff to a backup drive and start over.

I found the answer is an online article [here](https://radagast.ca/linux/mounting-ubuntu-encrypted-zfs.html).